# Excel: How to best sort/match two (+) columns with a different amount of rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

Hello I am trying to figure out a few different ways to accomplish this, to find the most efficient approach. Any and all help appreciated.

Here is one workaround I found but cum er some and does not always work (step 2.1) https://www.exceldemy.com/how-to-sort-two-columns-in-excel-to-match/

[image]

Comment: Move the list off to another range and use XLOOKUP.